# How can I add string pairs to a document of rapidjson

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I want to create a json string using rapidjson. But I got a error: unable to convert `std::string` to `rapidjson::Type`.

```
int x = 111;
string className = "myclass";

Document doc;
auto& allocator = doc.GetAllocator();

doc.AddMember("x", Value().SetInt(x), allocator);
doc.AddMember("className", className, allocator);

unordered_map<string, string>& map = sprite->toMap();
for (const auto& pair : map) {
    Value key(pair.first.c_str(), pair.first.size(), allocator);
    doc.AddMember(key, pair.second, allocator);
}

StringBuffer sb;
Writer<StringBuffer> writer(sb);

doc.Accept(writer);
log("json string: %s", sb.GetString());
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If `#define RAPIDJSON_HAS_STDSTRING 1` (before including rapidjson header files, or defined in compiling flags), there are some extra APIs for `std::string`.

To make "copy-strings" (allocated duplicates of source strings) of `std::string`, you can use constructor with allocator:

```
for (auto& pair : map) {
    rapidjson::Value key(pair.first, allocator);
    rapidjson::Value value(pair.second, allocator);
    doc.AddMember(key, value, allocator);
}
```

Or make it a single statement:

```
for (auto& pair : map)
    doc.AddMember(
        rapidjson::Value(pair.first, allocator).Move(),
        rapidjson::Value(pair.second, allocator).Move(),
        allocator);
```

If you presume that the lifetime of strings are longer than `doc`, then you can use "const-string" instead, which is simpler and more efficient:

```
for (auto& pair : map)
    doc.AddMember(
        rapidjson::StringRef(pair.first),
        rapidjson::StringRef(pair.second),
        allocator);
```

I think the macro `RAPIDJSON_HAS_STDSTRING` should be documented better...

Comment: The #define RAPIDJSON_HAS_STDSTRING 1 !

Answer (score 7):

Now, I realise that I have made 2 mistake: 
1. I should invoke `doc.SetObject();` after `doc` is created.
2. [How to create string in rapidjson](http://rapidjson.org/md_doc_tutorial.html#CreateString).

```
Document doc;
doc.SetObject();
auto& allocator = doc.GetAllocator();

rapidjson::Value s;
s = StringRef(className.c_str());
doc.AddMember("className", s, allocator);

auto& map = sprite->toJson();
for (auto& pair : map) {
    rapidjson::Value key(pair.first.c_str(), pair.first.size(), allocator);
    rapidjson::Value value(pair.second.c_str(), pair.second.size(), allocator);
    doc.AddMember(key, value, allocator);
}
```

There should be some better way to do it.